# PHP DateTime Comparison

Tags: php, datetime, comparison

I've become accostomed to using the identical comparison operator in PHP (===), instead of the equal comparison operator (==).  I ran into an issue while using php's built in DateTime objects.  I'm confused as to why the equal comparison return true, but the identical comparison return false in the following code?

Code:

```
$test1 = new DateTime("now");       // What I thought were identical objects
$test2 = new DateTime("now");       // 
$test3 = new DateTime("tomorrow");

echo("test1: ");
var_dump($test1);
echo("<br/>test2: ");
var_dump($test2);

echo("now === now: ");
var_dump($test1 === $test2);

echo("<br/>now == now: ");
var_dump($test1 == $test2);

echo("<br/>now < now: ");
var_dump($test1 < $test2);

echo("<br/>now > now: ");
var_dump($test1 > $test2);

echo("<br/>now < tomorrow: ");
var_dump($test2 < $test3);

echo("<br/>now > tomorrow: ");
var_dump($test2 > $test3);
```

Output:

```
    test1: object(DateTime)#36 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-06-23 14:44:25" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "America/Chicago" } 
    test2: object(DateTime)#37 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-06-23 14:44:25" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "America/Chicago" } 
    now === now: bool(false) 
    now == now: bool(true) 
    now < now: bool(false) 
    now > now: bool(false) 
    now < tomorrow: bool(true) 
    now > tomorrow: bool(false)
```

Comment: Be careful, it's entirely possible that `$test1` and `$test2` could fail on `==` if the time changed in between those two constructor calls.

Comment: Wouldn't the == fail then as well?

Comment: === will check to see if you are comparing the same object. $test1 and $test2 have different instances of the same object type, which is why === returns false. == just checks the value which is why this returns true.

Comment: @Maxxi:  Edited to show output of $test1 and $test2, so it fails because of the instance number (#36 and #37)? Whereas if I cloned it it would return true?

Comment: maybe interesting?: [Carbon: A simple PHP API extension for DateTime](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). The ['comparison' docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison).

Comment: Cloning $test1 will into $test2 will still return false with a === comparison as clone instantiates a new object and then clones the state of $test1. For $test2 to point to the same object you assign it like so: $test2 = $test1. They will then point to the same object and return true on a ($test1 === $test2) comparison.

Comment: @Maxxi comment is the best reply here in my opinion. Also RyanVincent proposal is a good choice. Carbon is a very extended package well tested and superb useful. I'll recommend you to give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of object comparision `===` not only check value and object type but it will check references also. That's why in your case `===` returns false because of two separate instance.

Just to clarify check this out:-

https://eval.in/386378

Note:- In the first case two separate instances are there `$test1` and `$test2`, that's why `===` returns false even object type and there values are equal.

But in the second case since `$test1` and `$test2` are same references so it states `true`.

Also in case of normal variables `===` check only value and datatype. where as `==` always checks values only and whenever datatype will different it will not give correct output. So be careful when using `==`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite clear to me that you are initializing test1 and test2 on two different lines. Most likeley they return different values and hence comparison will return false.

However the real issue is Identical Operator compares object .. and returns false if the object are different [that is referenced to different objects].

```
<?php

class Foo{}

$Foo1 = new Foo();
$Foo2 = new Foo();

echo ("Foo1 === Foo2");
var_dump($Foo1 === $Foo2);
```

Result in ::

```
Foo1 === Foo2bool(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you create the variables in sequence the result must be"false" because the datetime('now') in php returns the time at the moment so the seconds change for each variable however the problem could be   because not set this  parameter date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

```
    php > var_dump($test1);
       object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
       ["date"]=>
       string(26) "2015-06-23 15:46:34.000000"
       ["timezone_type"]=>
       int(3)
       ["timezone"]=>
       string(16) "America/New_York"
     }
     php > var_dump($test2);
     object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
     ["date"]=>
     string(26) "2015-06-23 15:46:38.000000"
     ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
     string(16) "America/New_York"
    }
```

Comment: Computers are fast. More often that not, two new datetimes set to "now" in succession will be the exact same time.